# When to use different SecurityContextHolder strategies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am reading Spring Security documentation it says that SecurityContextHolder provides different types of strategy for apps with specific thread behaviour. For example - Swing applications.

I understood that in web apps we can use ThredLocal strategy. But when to use other 2 strategies and how they work I cant understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects):

> **SecurityContextHolder, SecurityContext and Authentication Objects**
>
> The most fundamental object is `SecurityContextHolder`. This is where we store details of the present security context of the application, which includes details of the principal currently using the application. By default the `SecurityContextHolder` uses a `ThreadLocal` to store these details, which means that the security context is always available to methods in the same thread of execution, even if the security context is not explicitly passed around as an argument to those methods. Using a `ThreadLocal` in this way is quite safe if care is taken to clear the thread after the present principal’s request is processed. Of course, Spring Security takes care of this for you automatically so there is no need to worry about it.
>
> Some applications aren’t entirely suitable for using a `ThreadLocal`, because of the specific way they work with threads. For example, a Swing client might want all threads in a Java Virtual Machine to use the same security context. `SecurityContextHolder` can be configured with a strategy on startup to specify how you would like the context to be stored. For a standalone application you would use the `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL` strategy. Other applications might want to have threads spawned by the secure thread also assume the same security identity. This is achieved by using `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`. You can change the mode from the default `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL` in two ways. The first is to set a system property, the second is to call a static method on `SecurityContextHolder`. Most applications won’t need to change from the default, but if you do, take a look at the JavaDoc for `SecurityContextHolder` to learn more.